# Is it possible to login to an Oracle schema using a certificate?

Tags: oracle, security, certificate

The question is based on having to deal with lots of automated processing (testing, mostly). As it stands, all the schemas used have the same well known password, which is stored in lots of configuration files, which is bad from a security perspective. Using encrypted passwords does not really cut it.
So the question is: Does Oracle DB allow the use of client certificates for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer is yes. I am working on encrypting my listener. But it would start with building a wallet. Since I use Linux i use cron and OS authentication for jobs that I want to  run. You can do something similar with Windows. Just make sure that remote OS authentication is turned off.

Comment: OP may want to look into `CREATE USER .. IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY AS 'certificate_DN'` also.  It seems like you would still need to use an Oracle Wallet.